# Move a file if all 6th fields are 0

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to be able to check a file to see if all records are 0 within a file and if they are to then move the file.

I have written the script, ran it, no errors, but it does not move the file, can anyone please suggest why?

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`cat conc_upld_atp.11002.20141204151900.dat | awk -F , '{ print $6 }' |     uniq`
if [ result = "1" ]; then
    mv conc_upld_atp.11002.20141204151900.dat home/stephenb/scripttest
fi
```

Comment: not very sure what `cat file | awk '{print $6}' | uniq` pretends to do. Could you [edit] the question showing a sample file and desired output?

Comment: @fedorqui I'd assume the desired result could be achieved using `awk -F, '$6!=0{exit 1}' file && mv file newfile`

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ this is very clever. I added it into my answer. But if you feel like adding your own answer, feel free to rollback my change.

Comment: @fedorqui It's fine i wasn't planning on writing an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In Bash `=` compares strings; to you compare integers you need `-eq`:

```
if [ "$result" -eq 1 ]; then
```

Note that it is preferred to say `var=$(command)`. Also, your command `cat file | awk '...'` can be simplified to just `awk '...' file`. And depending on what exactly you want to do, probably `awk` can handle all of it.

For example, if you just want to check if any of the 6th fields are not `0`, just use:

```
awk '$1 != 0 {v=1} END {print v+0}' file
```

and then the rest of your code.

---

However, you can do it in a extremely fast way by using what [９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104645/linux-script-not-working-newbie-to-linux-scripting#comment54024766_33104645):

```
awk -F, '$6!=0{exit 1}' file && mv file newfile
```

This loops through the file and exits with a code error if any line contains a 6th field different from `0`. If this does not happen, `awk`'s exit code is 0, so that the `&&` command is performed and, hence, `mv file newfile` happens. You can even keep track of the other condition by saying:

```
awk -F, '$6!=0{exit 1}' file && mv file newfile || echo "bad data"
```

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini `$result` contains the result of the `uniq` above, so this is almost guaranteed to fail anyway, unless the original file had one line.

Comment: OK, So i want to check if the 6th field has nothing but 0's, so in effect the whole file in the 6th field has 0's and if true to move the file, what is the most effective way that could be written?

Comment: @StephenButlerWorrall you can use my suggested `awk` or -even better- the recommendation under your answer.

Comment: Note: you'll see the "bad data" message if the mv command fails for any reason.

Comment: @glennjackman good point. Is there any way to distinguish one failure from the other? I was thinking in some kind of `{ awk -F .... && mv } || echo "bad data"` but not sure if it is the answer.

Comment: You have to use `if awk ...; then mv ...; else echo ...; fi`

Comment: @fedorqui, you could always include the message in the awk. `'$6!=0{print "bad data";exit 1}'`

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to check if all records are `0`, but you specifically check `result = "1"`.

I would recommend two things: use numerical comparison and compare against the correct value:

```
if (( result == 0 )); then
```

Comment: I want to check if field number 6, has a 0 for each row in that field, and if so to move the file.

Answer (score -1):

If you want check whether all fields is 0, then try this script:

```
result=`cat conc_upld_atp.11002.20141204151900.dat | awk '{ print $6 }' |     uniq`

if [ "$result" == "0" ]; then
  mv conc_upld_atp.11002.20141204151900.dat /home/stephenb/scripttest
fi
```

Comment: tried that and it does not work.  again runs without error but wont move the file??

Comment: i modified my script, check it.

Comment: I have just tried your same piece of code and it will not work??

Comment: i tried this code, and work... I'm sorry that you can not apply.

Answer (score -2):

In the end i used the below.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`cat conc_upld_atp.11002.20141204151900.dat | awk -F , '{ print $6 }' |         uniq`
resultcount=`echo $result | wc -l`
echo $resultcount
if [ $resultcount == "1" ]; then
echo match
mv conc_upld_atp.11002.20141204151900.dat /home/stephenb/scripttest
fi
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to do it, it would move the file if none of the lines contained 0.

Comment: awk '{ print $6 }' see my answer